# Passing const char * to a function in C

Tags: c, char, constants

I'm trying to write a that function takes a `const char *` as a parameter, and I can't figure out how to pass this kind of data to a function in a useful way. If I have function:

```
void tokenize(const char * c) { }
```

And I want to call this function with a hardcoded value, say backslash, what is the best way to approach this? How do I turn a hardcoded value into a `const char *`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals are perfectly legal to use in place of a `const char *` parameter:

```
tokenize("\\");
```

A more illustrative example would be to store a pointer to that string and then pass that pointer:

```
const char *token = "\\";
tokenize(token);
```

String literals are not, however, compatible with `char *`, even though the compiler may permit it. This has to do with the way string literals are stored - they are usually located in a read-only area of memory and an attempt to write to them will cause undefined behaviour, most probably some kind of a protection fault.

Comment: It works because (the address of) a hardcoded literal string **is** a `const char *`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck In C, string literals are of type `char []` without `const`.

Comment: @Yu Hao I always treat them as `const`, because they are often stored in a read-only area of memory. With that in mind it is really irrelevant whether the specification say that they are `const` or not.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Sure modifying string literals are undefined behavior. But from the syntax level, their correct type isn't `const char *`. Respect the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string literal like `"\\"` and pass it as an argument to the function.